# Street cleaning in France led to broken leg - Can City be sued?

Tags: liability, france, accident

My brother is Irish (thus EU citizen) he moved to Nice, France earlier this year to work in a bar restaurant. He finished work at 530am, street cleaners were out (Nice City power wash/clean many streets). Slippy cobblestones led to a slip and he broke his leg and ankle (twice in tibia, twice in fibia?).

His alcohol level was tested and not considered a contributing factor to the accident (the doctors said his alcohol count measured below the drink driving limit).

There were witnesses to his fall.

He has been told his work health insurance will cover the medical bills and salary for up to three months. He will spend about a month in a wheelchair before (hopefully) moving to crutches for a couple of months.

He is uncomfortable/unwilling to seek recourse in the courts. I'm suggesting otherwise. Is it worth exploring or would French law just deem it bad luck?

Comment: I don't know whether the government would cover it on the merits, but the French Council of State would be the body that would handle the claim and claim forms are available at many retail stores in France and it is a quite cheap and easy process. If a claim form is filed, an attorney-investigator is assigned to follow up on non-frivolous claims on your behalf and another is appointed to protect the government's interest and they work it out. You might want to check the Council of State website. Generally, government liability is broad in France, but tort liability is tepid, so mixed signals.